# Create Event Trigger Based on Date

Tags: sql, postgresql

Let's say currently I'm having a table which consists a column named as 'next_update' in date format, I can calculate the time left (in day) by simply subtract the value in 'next_update' with the current date using sql command, however, how could I able to create an event trigger that automatically update some data in this table to another table when the time left for example is equal to 2. I'm using postgresql as my database.

Appreciate and thank you for any help.

Comment: I think you need to set up a cron job or some similar scheduled event to handle this.

Comment: @GordonLinoff where could I found some simple examples for this kind of work for postgresql of windows. tQ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a function in your database that when called: check date/time difference and update another table if necessary. You can achieve this by doing a simple batch script, which is called regularly by a cron job (Depends on OS) or [pgAgent](http://www.pgadmin.org/docs/1.4/pgagent-install.html).